# How to make walls opaque in PuzzleScript

Tags: puzzle

On the PuzzleScript [home page](https://www.puzzlescript.net/Documentation/rules101.html), there is an [example](https://www.puzzlescript.net/editor.html?demo=sokoban_eyeball) of an enemy (`Eyeball`) which, when you (`Player`) are directly in its line of sight, will move one square closer to you, using the rule

```
[ Eyeball | ... | Player ] -> [ > Eyeball | ... | Player ]
```

However, the `Eyeball` will walk towards `Player` even if it shouldn't be able to see you, for instance if there is a wall in the way. This is apparent in a level like

```
#########
#....O..#
#.......#
#########
#.......#
#..P....#
#########
```

where, if `Player` passes below `Eyeball`, `Eyeball` will move one square down.

How do I make it so that the enemy can't see me through walls?

Inserting `no Wall` into the rule above doesn't work, as that doesn't tell `...` to only match wall-free tiles, but rather checks whether there is at least one non-wall tile between `Eyeball` and `Player`. And adding the rule

```
[ > Eyeball | ... | Wall | ... | Player ] -> [ Eyeball | ... | Wall | ... | Player ]
```

in an attempt to correct the movement doesn't work as two ellipses in a single match pattern isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across a solution which works. It basically uses a phantom block to raycast from `Player` to any `Eyeball` in line with the `Player`, and if that block hits an `Eyeball` before it hits a `Wall`, it will make the `Eyeball` move toward the `Player`:

```
[Player | Eyeball] -> [Player | < Eyeball]
[Player | no Wall |... | EyeBall] -> [ Player | > Gaze | ... | Eyeball]
[> Gaze | no Wall | ... | Eyeball ] -> [ | > Gaze | ... | Eyeball ]
+ [> Gaze | Eyeball ] -> [ | < Eyeball > Gaze]
[ Gaze ] -> []
```

This works fine even for multiple `Eyeball`s, apart form some slight hiccups when Eyeballs compete for a square. That is to say, if you have two `Eyeball`s both touching the `Player`, and the `Player` moves out of the way, only one `Eyeball` will move to fill in the spot left by the `Player`, and which one that turns out to be is decided by the engine when the movement occurs.

(This competition would probably be tricky to solve using rules because doing so would require to match patterns that are not along a single line.)

If there is only one `Eyeball`, then the first two rules may be put together and simplified to

```
[Player | ... | EyeBall] -> [ Player > Gaze | ... | Eyeball]
```

This runs into issues with more than one `Eyeball` because several `Gaze` blocks cannot coexist in the same cell, meaning only one `Gaze` block ever gets made. One could also mend this by putting `again` after each rule, but that would make moves not happen instantaneously so it's not optimal.